# Claws-mail keyboard shortcut to load remote content

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, images, claws-mail, html-mail

I am new to Claws Mail, I have just set it up on a Windows 7 machine; I have enabled the "Fancy" plugin, and found the "Setting/plugins/fancy/enable loading remote content" setting.

I have also found the little "tools" icon at the bottom left of the message view window, next to the magnifying glasses to adjust zoom. This little icon, when clicked, opens a much useful menu, where you can enable remote image loading on the particular message you are viewing.

Finally, there is the option in claws mail to assign customized keyboard shortcuts to a menu option that is highlighted by the mouse. It does work on all the "regular" menu entries, from the menu toolbar on top.

Unfortunately, as I am guessing, the menu that opens when you click the little "tools" icon at the bottom left of the message window, is not the same kind of menu (i.e.: it is a menu that belongs to the Fancy plugin itself), and when highlighting "enable loading remote content", and pressing, e.g., "ctrl+y", nothing happens, no shortcut is assigned.

**So now I ask: is there a quick way in principle, to toggle the fetching of remote content on/off with a simple keyboard shortcut, for each particular message?** As it appears, the old gtkhtml2 viewer (which does not work on Windows anyway) had a button to enable displaying remote images for each email you were viewing. Regular webmails like Roundcube also have those (although they have other huge problems). But in Claws on Windows with Fancy plugin only, **you have to click a tiny icon, and then a menu entry**, to do the same.

**How can I do it faster?** Maybe a way to enter it as actions/execute? For this I would need to know how to reference this menu option/check box in a line of code and change it...

PS: I am using a French version of the software, so the exact name of the menu entries referenced here, which I translated back to English, might be slightly different in the original English Claws Mail.

Comment: Same question here. I would like to enable automatic loading of remote content only for some known mail senders and have it disabled (=manual) otherwise. Having all the remote contents loading always on is a security/privacy risk, but one also gets tired of clicking that icon. A keyboard shortcut would be a great solution.